# Installing and using php-symfony-* components

Tags: php, symfony

on my ubuntu machine I have installed php-symfony-routing using apt-get. When I tried to run the following code, the below error message appeared.

```
<?php
$routes = new \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection();
```

Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection' not found in
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is because the script doesn't know how to find that class.

I wouldn't recommend installing a library in this way.

Take a look at the [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing.html) and look into using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Once composer has installed the dependency for you, you can use its autoloader, which the script uses to locate the classes you're using.

```
composer require symfony/routing
```

The above creates a vendor directory and installs the package into it. It also creates an autoloader for you to use.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$routes = new \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection();
```

The advantage of Composer is not only the ease of use and autoloader, but it allows you to specify each of your projects' dependencies. Different projects may well require different versions of different libraries. There's a bunch of other stuff too but that'd be way beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: What I wanted to do is to find out when apt-get install php-symfony-routing runs what it does and if there any benefits using this approach.

Comment: From what I have seen the lib has been installed under the following directory /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Routing and now I can do the following to load the library using composer.json                                                                               "/usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Routing/autoload.php"]                                                                                                                             What I want to ask, has anyone tried this approach and if so what are the prons and cons that he find out.

Comment: Advantage of composer is in the answer. To use the package the way you have it currently, require the path to the autoload.php that you've just mentioned in your script. Disadvantages of apt method include having to wait for package maintainers to update, and it masking the required dependencies for your project.